# Calculate boundary of two domains

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

$D_1 =\{ -1 \le x \le 1-\sqrt{y^2+z^2}\}$

$D_2 =\{ x^2+y^2+z^2\le 8,z\ge 2\}$

Is it correct to say that the boundary of $D_1$ is :

$B(D_1) =\{ (x-1)^2=y^2+z^2,(x+1)^2=y^2+z^2\}$

and the boundary of $D_2$ :

$B(D_2) =\{z\ge 2 ,x^2+y^2+z^2=8 \} \cup \{x^2+y^2=4\}$

?

Especially the last one. I know for sure that the boundary is $x^2+y^2=4$, but i'm not sure that the boundary is also the 'cover' of the shpere($x^2+y^2+z^2=8$)

Answer (score 1):

$C= \{x \in \mathbb R^3 ; x^2+y^2=4\}$ is not a subset of $B(D_2)$. $C$ is the right circular cylinder of axis $Oz$ and with radius $2$. $C$ is unbounded while $D_2$ is bounded. What is true is that 
$$B(D_2) = \{z\ge 2 ,x^2+y^2+z^2=8 \} \cup \{z=2, x^2+y^2 \le 4\}.$$

Your $B(D_1)$ isn't correct either. To "compute" the boundary, use the fact that one of the inequality has to be an equality and look at what it implies for the second inequality.

Comment: Can you help me with B(D_1) please? is $B(D_1)= \{ (x-1)^2 -y^2 -z^2 \ge -1\}U\{(x-2)^2 -y^2 -z^2 =0\}$ ?

Comment: I would encourage you to find it by yourself using the hint I provided in the answer. Suppose that $x=-1$, what inequality does it imply for $x \le 1-\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$? And conversely if $x = 1-\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$?

Comment: ok I got it! Thanks